# Why does set -e not work inside subshells with parenthesis () followed by an OR list ||?

Tags: shell, shell-script

I've run across some scripting like this recently:

```
( set -e ; do-stuff; do-more-stuff; ) || echo failed
```

This looks fine to me, but it does not work!  The `set -e` does not apply, when you add the `||`.  Without that, it works fine:

```
$ ( set -e; false; echo passed; ); echo $?
1
```

However, if I add the `||`, the `set -e` is ignored:

```
$ ( set -e; false; echo passed; ) || echo failed
passed
```

Using a real, separate shell works as expected:

```
$ sh -c 'set -e; false; echo passed;' || echo failed
failed
```

I've tried this in multiple different shells (bash, dash, ksh93) and all behave the same way, so it's not a bug.  Can someone explain this?

Comment: The `(....)``construct starts a separate shell to run its contents, any settings in it don't apply outside.

Comment: @vonbrand, you missed the point.  He wants it to apply inside the subshell, but the `||` outside the subshell affects the behavior inside the subshell.

Comment: Compare `(set -e; echo 1; false; echo 2)` with `(set -e; echo 1; false; echo 2) || echo 3`

Comment: from [stackoverflow here is a good workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11092989/52074) --> `set +e ; ( set -e; f ) ; err_status=$?; set -e; ` then you can do an if statement on the `err_status`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/gnu.bash.bug/NCK_0GmIv2M/discussion), it's the behavior POSIX specifies for using "`set -e`" in a subshell.

(I was surprised as well.)

First, the behavior:

> The `-e` setting shall be ignored when executing the compound
>   list following the while, until, if, or elif reserved word, 
>   a pipeline beginning with the ! reserved word, or any 
>   command of an AND-OR list other than the last.

The second post notes,

> > In summary, shouldn't set -e in (subshell code) operate independently 
> >     of the surrounding context?
>
> No.  The POSIX description is clear that surrounding context affects 
>   whether set -e is ignored in a subshell.

There's a little more in the fourth post, also by Eric Blake,

> Point 3 is *not* requiring subshells to override the contexts where `set 
>   -e` is ignored.  That is, once you are in a context where `-e` is ignored, 
>   there is **nothing** you can do to get `-e` obeyed again, not even a subshell.
>
> ```
> $ bash -c 'set -e; if (set -e; false; echo hi); then :; fi; echo $?' 
> hi 
> 0
> ```
>
> Even though we called `set -e` twice (both in the parent and in the 
>   subshell), the fact that the subshell exists in a context where `-e` is 
>   ignored (the condition of an if statement), there is nothing we can do 
>   in the subshell to re-enable `-e`.

This behavior is definitely surprising. It is counter-intuitive: one would expect the re-enabling of `set -e` to have an effect, and that the surrounding context would not take precedent; further, the wording of the POSIX standard does not make this particularly clear. If you read it in the context where the command is failing, the rule does not apply: it only applies in the surrounding context, however, it applies to it completely.

Comment: Thanks for those links, they were very interesting.  However, my example is (IMO) substantively different.  Most of that discussion is whether set -e in a parent shell is inherited by the subshell: `set -e; (false; echo passed;) || echo failed`.  It does not surprise me, actually, that -e is ignored in this case given the wording of the standard.  In my case, though, I'm explicitly setting -e _in the subshell_, and expecting _the subshell_ to exit on failure.  There's no AND-OR list in the subshell...

Comment: I disagree. The second post (I can't get the anchors to work) says "*The POSIX description is clear that surrounding context affects whether set -e is ignored in a subshell.*" - the subshell is in the AND-OR list.

Comment: The fourth post (also Erik Blake) also says "*Even though we called set -e twice (both in the parent and in the
subshell), the fact that the subshell exists in a context where -e is ignored (the condition of an if statement), there is nothing we can do in the subshell to re-enable -e.*"

Comment: You're right; I'm not sure how I misread those.  Thanks.

Comment: I am delighted to learn that this behavior I'm tearing my hair out over turns out to be in POSIX spec. So what is the work around?! `if` and `||` and `&&` are infectious? this is absurd

Comment: BTW `set -e` works as we might expect it to, inside bash in OS X so i am running my test script on Linux now and it happily keeps on going when everything fails. Because I wrote my script on OS X.

Comment: @StevenLu, see [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254676/583610) which explains how to fix this.

Comment: very un-intuitive. arg. :|.

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco :waves: Just stumbled on your answer while looking this up :)

Comment: @Iguananaut LOL yeah about every two to three months I get a notification that somebody else stumbled upon this giant "WTF?" 9 years and counting...

Comment: 11 years LOL... @Shayan I wouldn't expect it to crash on `if` because the `if` is using the result. `set -e` is to exit on an _uncaptured_ error condition.

Answer (score 14):

Indeed, `set -e` has no effect inside subshells if you use `||` operator after them; e.g., this wouldn't work:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# prints:
#
# --> outer
# --> inner
# ./so_1.sh: line 16: some_failed_command: command not found
# <-- inner
# <-- outer

set -e

outer() {
  echo '--> outer'
  (inner) || {
    exit_code=$?
    echo '--> cleanup'
    return $exit_code
  }
  echo '<-- outer'
}

inner() {
  set -e
  echo '--> inner'
  some_failed_command
  echo '<-- inner'
}

outer
```

Aaron D. Marasco [in his answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65564/58361) does a great job of explaining why it behaves this way.

Here is a little trick that can be used to fix this: run the inner command in background, and then immediately wait for it. The `wait` builtin will return the exit code of the inner command, and now you're using `||` after `wait`, not the inner function, so `set -e` works properly inside the latter:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# prints:
#
# --> outer
# --> inner
# ./so_2.sh: line 27: some_failed_command: command not found
# --> cleanup

set -e

outer() {
  echo '--> outer'
  inner &
  wait $! || {
    exit_code=$?
    echo '--> cleanup'
    return $exit_code
  }
  echo '<-- outer'
}

inner() {
  set -e
  echo '--> inner'
  some_failed_command
  echo '<-- inner'
}

outer
```

Here is the generic function that builds upon this idea. It should work in all POSIX-compatible shells if you remove `local` keywords, i.e. replace all `local x=y` with just `x=y`:

```sh
# [CLEANUP=cleanup_cmd] run cmd [args...]
#
# `cmd` and `args...` A command to run and its arguments.
#
# `cleanup_cmd` A command that is called after cmd has exited,
# and gets passed the same arguments as cmd. Additionally, the
# following environment variables are available to that command:
#
# - `RUN_CMD` contains the `cmd` that was passed to `run`;
# - `RUN_EXIT_CODE` contains the exit code of the command.
#
# If `cleanup_cmd` is set, `run` will return the exit code of that
# command. Otherwise, it will return the exit code of `cmd`.
#
run() {
  local cmd="$1"; shift
  local exit_code=0

  local e_was_set=1; if ! is_shell_attribute_set e; then
    set -e
    e_was_set=0
  fi

  "$cmd" "$@" &

  wait $! || {
    exit_code=$?
  }

  if [ "$e_was_set" = 0 ] && is_shell_attribute_set e; then
    set +e
  fi

  if [ -n "$CLEANUP" ]; then
    RUN_CMD="$cmd" RUN_EXIT_CODE="$exit_code" "$CLEANUP" "$@"
    return $?
  fi

  return $exit_code
}


is_shell_attribute_set() { # attribute, like "x"
  case "$-" in
    *"$1"*) return 0 ;;
    *)    return 1 ;;
  esac
}
```

Example of usage:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Source the file with the definition of `run` (previous code snippet).
# Alternatively, you may paste that code directly here and comment the next line.
. ./utils.sh


main() {
  echo "--> main: $@"
  CLEANUP=cleanup run inner "$@"
  echo "<-- main"
}


inner() {
  echo "--> inner: $@"
  sleep 0.5; if [ "$1" = 'fail' ]; then
    oh_my_god_look_at_this
  fi
  echo "<-- inner"
}


cleanup() {
  echo "--> cleanup: $@"
  echo "    RUN_CMD = '$RUN_CMD'"
  echo "    RUN_EXIT_CODE = $RUN_EXIT_CODE"
  sleep 0.3
  echo '<-- cleanup'
  return $RUN_EXIT_CODE
}

main "$@"
```

Running the example:

```sh
$ ./so_3 fail; echo "exit code: $?"

--> main: fail
--> inner: fail
./so_3: line 15: oh_my_god_look_at_this: command not found
--> cleanup: fail
    RUN_CMD = 'inner'
    RUN_EXIT_CODE = 127
<-- cleanup
exit code: 127

$ ./so_3 pass; echo "exit code: $?"

--> main: pass
--> inner: pass
<-- inner
--> cleanup: pass
    RUN_CMD = 'inner'
    RUN_EXIT_CODE = 0
<-- cleanup
<-- main
exit code: 0
```

The only thing that you need to be aware of when using this method is that all modifications of Shell variables done from the command you pass to `run` will not propagate to the calling function, because the command runs in a subshell.

Comment: Another workaround: Do something like `my_func() { ( set -x; my_commands; ...; ) }; set +x; my_func; return_code=$?; set -x`. It's dumb, but maybe more compact, and still prevents the parent script from prematurely existing?

Comment: Ah, Ciro had done this here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/452584/304032

Comment: I think `wait` exit status 127 (i.e. the background job has already exited by the time `wait` is called) needs to be treated as 0. Of course, you'd lose the detection of a status 127 in the inner command, but that's the lesser of two evils, I guess.

Comment: Nice trick with the background job. However, why set `-e` in the generic run function? run shouldn't need it, and without it, it would more flexible by letting the caller choose (plus simpler).

Answer (score 2):

**Workaround when usint toplevel `set -e`**

I came to this question because I was using `set -e` as an error detection method:

```
/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
do_stuff
( take_best_sub_action_1; take_best_sub_action_2 ) || do_worse_fallback
do_more_stuff
```

and without `||`, the script would stop running and never reach `do_more_stuff`.

Since there seems to be no clean solution, I think I will be just doing a simple `set +e` on my scripts:

```
/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
do_stuff
set +e
( take_best_sub_action_1; take_best_sub_action_2 )
exit_status=$?
set -e
if [ "$exit_status" -ne 0 ]; then
  do_worse_fallback
fi
do_more_stuff
```

Comment: I think OP wants take_best_sub_action_2 to be skipped if take_best_sub_action_1 fails, so this is not a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't rule out it's a bug just because several shells behave that way. ;-)

I have more fun to offer:

```
start cmd:> ( eval 'set -e'; false; echo passed; ) || echo failed
passed

start cmd:> ( eval 'set -e; false'; echo passed; ) || echo failed
failed

start cmd:> ( eval 'set -e; false; echo passed;' ) || echo failed
failed
```

May I quote from man bash (4.2.24):

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is [...] part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or || [...]

Perhaps the eval over several commands leads to ignoring the || context.

Comment: Well, if all the shells behave that way it's by definition not a bug... it's standard behavior :-).  We may lament the behavior as non-intuitive but...  The trick with eval is very interesting, that's for sure.

Comment: What shell do you use? The `eval` trick does not work for me. I tried bash, bash in posix mode, and dash.

Comment: @Dunatotatos, as Hauke said, that was bash4.2. It was "fixed" in bash4.3. pdksh-based shells will have the same "issue". And several versions of several shells have all sorts of different "issues" with `set -e`. `set -e` is broken by design. I wouldn't use it for anything but the simplest of shell scripts without control structures, subshells or command substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

Approach with running command in a background [suggested by @skozin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254676/397821) won't work in `bash`. `bash` still disables `set -e` for background commands. `dash` and `ash` work fine though.