# Local `set -e` for functions

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

Is there such a feature or can it be emulated reasonably easily?
I want the same behavior except it should `return` where `set -e` would have caused a call to `exit`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sub shell might be useful.

```
func() {(set -e
        echo a
        ehco b
        echo c
)}

func
func
func
```

This script produces:

```
a
script.sh: line 3: ehco: command not found
a
script.sh: line 3: ehco: command not found
a
script.sh: line 3: ehco: command not found
```

Alternatively you might be interested in [this try/catch implemetation in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29976424/4937930).

Comment: No need for the braces in this case: `func () ( … )` is equivalent. Note that since the function is executed in a subshell, its variable assignments, redirections, etc. won't affect the caller.

Comment: This fails to early-out if you run `func && foo`, `if func then ... fi` or similar constructs which depend on the exit status of `func`. [See explanation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65564/85237).

Answer (score 8):

You can set the `ERR` trap, which is executed whenever a command returns a nonzero status.

In bash, it's a bit fiddly because traps are not local to functions. By default, traps are not inherited by subshells or subfunctions; call `set -E` to change this. Here's some demo code.

```
#!/bin/bash

subroutine () {
  false
  echo "Subroutine continued after status $?"
}

trapper () {
  local i ret
  trap 'ret=$?
        echo "Command $BASH_COMMAND returned status $ret"
        for ((i=0; i<$((${#FUNCNAME[@]}-1)); i++)) do
          echo "  from ${FUNCNAME[$i]} at ${BASH_SOURCE[$((i+1))]} line ${BASH_LINENO[$((i+1))]}"
        done
        return $ret' ERR
  trap 'ret=$?; trap - ERR RETURN; return $ret' RETURN
  echo ok
  subroutine
  echo "By default, the ERR trap is not inherited"
  false
  echo "You won't see this"
}

main () {
  trapper
  echo "trapper returned status $?"
  false
  echo "still there"
}

main
```

In zsh, you can define the `TRAPZERR` function instead of setting a trap for `ERR` (for compatibility) or `ZERR` (on systems with a signal called `SIGERR` — I don't know of any). But if all you want to do is return immediately (and not e.g. print an error message), it's simpler: just set the `err_return` option. Options are global by default; set the `local_options` option to make them local to the calling function (if the `local_options` option is set when a function returns, the options from the time the function was called are restored). Traps are also global by default. Options and traps are inherited in function calls.

```
myfunction () {
  setopt local_options err_return
  false
  echo not executed
}
```

Comment: It does not look like the zsh solution has the behavior of `set -o pipefail`, just `set -e`. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Oh, silly me assuming the online docs would be up to date. Recent versions of zsh have a `setopt pipe_fail` which works just fine.

Comment: @RadonRosborough `pipefail` was outside the scope of the question. In bash, ksh and zsh you can do `set -o pipefail` (note that this isn't local to the function, except in zsh if you call `setopt local_options` in the function). This is not new and the online documentation is up-to-date, but not very easy to read.

Comment: You're right that the official manual at http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html is perfectly well up to date. I was looking at https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions from Google, which I should have been more clear about.

Answer (score 6):

With `ksh93`, if you use `ksh`'s own syntax for funtion definition (`function f {...;}`), then options and traps have a local scope. So there, you can do:

```
function f {
  trap 'return 99' ERR
  set -e
  echo foo
  false
  echo never output
}
f
echo "f exited with status $?"
```

Which gives:

```
foo
f exited with status 99
```