# set -e in a subshell

Tags: shell, subshell

I thought `set -e` had the same effect on subshells as on top-level shell.
Apparently, it does not. This:

```
(
  set -e
  false 
  true
) || echo false1


bash -ec '
  set -e
  false 
  true
' || echo false2


bash <<EOF || echo false3
  set -e
  false 
  true
EOF

bash <<EOF || echo false4
  false 
  true
EOF

bash <<EOF || echo false5
  false  &&
  true
EOF
```

Prints

```
false2
false3
false5
```

Where is this documented? Can I get subshells to terminate on errors, without connecting all their commands with `&&` (or without doing `|| exit $?` after each command)?

**Edit:**

My particular use case was something like:

```
set -e
  # ...
status=0
( false; true ) || status=$?
report_code $status
return $status
```

Where the contents of the subshell was my actual code.
The problem with this is it always sets status to 0 and replacing `||`
with `;` causes an unwanted error exit because of the outer set -e.

I solved it with:

```
set -e
  # ...
set +e
( false; true ); status=$?
set -e
report_code $status
return $status
```

I wish I didn't have to do this, but it appears all common shells show this
execed-subshell vs just-forked-subshell dichotomy:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo FORK\'D:
export SH
for SH in dash bash ksh zsh; do
    $SH -c 'st=0; ( set -e; false; true ) || st=$?; printf "%s\t%s\n" $SH  $st; '
done

echo EXEC\'D:
for SH in dash bash ksh zsh; do
    $SH -c 'st=0; '$SH' -c " set -e; false; true " || st=$?; printf "%s\t%s\n" $SH $st; '
done
```

OUTPUT:

```
FORK'D:
dash    0
bash    0
ksh 0
zsh 0
EXEC'D:
dash    1
bash    1
ksh 1
zsh 1
```

Comment: It's intended, read `-e` documentation part of [set](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does set -e not work inside subshells with parenthesis () followed by an OR list ||?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/why-does-set-e-not-work-inside-subshells-with-parenthesis-followed-by-an-or)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Observe:

```
$ ( set -e; false ; true ) || echo false1
$ ( set -e; false ; true ) ; echo code=$?
code=1
```

Also:

```
$ ( set -e; false ; true; echo inside=$? ) || echo false1
inside=0
```

Apparently, when the subshell is followed by a `||`, `set -e` does not cause the subshell to exit upon reaching the `false` command.  Instead, the subshell continues and executes `true` (and `echo inside=$?`).

The philosophy of `set -e` is typically that it only exits upon uncaught errors.  Here, the presence of `||` outside the subshell seems to tell the shell that the error inside the subshell is 'caught' and therefore `set -e` does not cause an exit after `false`.

`set -e` has many surprising behaviors.  See ["Why doesn't set -e do what I expected?"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ#BashFAQ.2F105.Why_doesn.27t_set_-e_.28or_set_-o_errexit.2C_or_trap_ERR.29_do_what_I_expected.3F)

#### Documentation

The behavior above is hinted at in the documentation in `man bash`:

> -e
>   Exit immediately if a pipeline (which may consist of a
>   single simple command), a list, or a compound command (see SHELL
>   GRAMMAR  above),   exits  with a non-zero status.  **The shell does not
>   exit if the command that fails is** part of the command list immediately
>   following a while or until keyword, part of the test following the if
>   or elif reserved words, **part of  any  command  executed  in  a  &&  or
>   || list** except the command following the final && or ||, any command
>   in a pipeline but the last, or if the       command's return value is
>   being inverted with !.  If a compound command other than a subshell
>   returns a non-zero status because   a  command  failed  while  -e  was
>   being ignored, the shell does not exit.  A trap on ERR, if set, is
>   executed before the shell exits.  This option applies to the shell
>   environment and each subshell environment separately (see COMMAND 
>   EXECUTION  ENVIRONMENT above), and may cause subshells to exit before
>   executing all the commands in the subshell. [Emphasis added.]

Comment: "The philosophy of set -e is typically that it only exits upon uncaught errors. Here, the presence of || outside the subshell seems to tell the shell that the error inside the subshell is 'caught' and therefore set -e does not cause an exit after false."
Yes, but the error inside the subshell is not reported. "false1" is not printed. It just masks the error, as if `set -e` was not in effect at all.

Comment: You appear to be talking about the case `( set -e; false ; true ) || echo false1`.  The subshell exits with the return code of the last command run.  Since `||` suppresses the the exit after `false`, the last command executed in the subshell is `true`.  Thus `false1` is not printed because the subshell exits with return code zero.