# try/finally with bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, exit-status

I have these three lines:

```
  export bunion_uds_file="$bunion_socks/$(uuidgen).sock";
  "$cmd" "$@" | bunion
  rm -f "$bunion_uds_file"
```

I need to make sure the last line always executes..I could do this:

```
  export bunion_uds_file="$bunion_socks/$(uuidgen).sock";
  (
    set +e
    "$cmd" "$@" | bunion
    rm -f "$bunion_uds_file"
  )
```

or maybe like this:

```
  export bunion_uds_file="$bunion_socks/$(uuidgen).sock";
  "$cmd" "$@" | bunion && rm -f "$bunion_uds_file" || rm -f "$bunion_uds_file"
```

I assume creating the subshell and using set +e is slightly less performant etc.

Comment: The common practice is to remove a unix domain socket _before_ binding to it. No try/finally, traps, etc could guard against your script just crashing or being killed by `SIGKILL`. Then the next instance will fail with `EADDRINUSE` when trying to bind to it.

Comment: @skozin's [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254676/133282) looks promising.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set a trap:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export bunion_uds_file="$bunion_socks/$(uuidgen).sock"
trap 'rm -f "$bunion_uds_file"' EXIT

"$cmd" "$@" | bunion
```

This would make the `rm -f` command run whenever the shell session terminates, except for when terminating by the `KILL` signal.

[As mosvy points out in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535057/try-finally-with-bash-shell/535061?noredirect=1#comment991356_535057), if this is a socket that needs to be cleaned up before use, it would be easier to remove it before recreating and using it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

export bunion_uds_file="$bunion_socks/$(uuidgen).sock"
rm -f "$bunion_uds_file" || exit 1

"$cmd" "$@" | bunion
```

Comment: I like to put the trap code in a function: `cleanup() { rm -f $thefile; }` and then `trap cleanup EXIT` -- I think it's cleaner, and it solves any quoting problems.

Comment: @glennjackman You've just introduced a quoting problem in that comment's code, but I get what you're saying. For just deleting a single file in a three line script, I personally think not using a function is ok.

Comment: Yes, bash (but not dash or zsh) will also call the `EXIT` trap when being killed by a `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM`, but I don't know how wise it is to rely on that.