# xargs does not quit on error

Tags: xargs, exit-status

I have a bash script where I use `find` to get a bunch of files in a directory, from which I then use `xargs` to execute said files in a chroot environment 1 script at a time. My understanding has been that xargs quits and stop processing once it sees a non-zero exit code, however, for some reason this does not seem to be the case.

The script I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -euo pipefail

script_dir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )/.." && pwd )

rootfs="$1"

exec_script() {
  script="$1"

  relative_script_path="$(realpath --relative-to="$script_dir" "$script")"

  echo -e "\e[1;94m=> executing script $script ($relative_script_path)\e[0m"

  sleep 5

  if ! "$rootfs/enter-chroot" sh -c "/$relative_script_path"; then
    echo -e "\e[1;31m=> script $script failed\e[0m"
    exit 1
  fi

  echo -e "\e[1;32m=> script $script ran successfully\e[0m"
}

export -f exec_script
export rootfs
export script_dir

find "$script_dir/build/scripts" -name '*.sh' -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r -0 -I% -n1 bash -c 'exec_script "$@"' _ %
```

And when I run it, I get the following output:

```
./build/run.sh /tmp/test
=> executing script /tmp/builder/build/scripts/000-upgrade.sh (build/scripts/000-upgrade.sh)
environment: line 4: /tmp/test/enter-chroot: Not a directory
=> script /tmp/builder/build/scripts/000-upgrade.sh failed
=> executing script /tmp/builder/build/scripts/001-firmware.sh (build/scripts/001-firmware.sh)
environment: line 4: /tmp/test/enter-chroot: Not a directory
=> script /tmp/builder/build/scripts/001-firmware.sh failed
```

Where am I going wrong? How can I ensure that xargs stops processing and exits with a non-zero exit code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `xargs` (see `man xargs`) actually says this about exiting,

> If any invocation of the command exits with a status of 255, `xargs` will stop immediately without reading any further input.  An error message is issued on *stderr* when this happens.

One possible solution would, therefore, be to change `exec_script` to return exit status 255 on error.

Another possible solution, in the case that `exec_script` cannot be changed, would be to turn the plain `xargs` into a shell loop:

```
find "$script_dir/build/scripts" -name '*.sh' -print0 |
    sort -z |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' item && exec_script _ "$item"; do :; done
```

Here the loop will break if `exec_script` returns any non-zero exit value.

Yet another solution, this one from the [comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566834/xargs-does-not-quit-on-error/566837#comment1054095_566837) and which arguably is the simplest external fix, is to catch any exit error from your script and replace it with 255:

```
find "$script_dir/build/scripts" -name '*.sh' -print0 |
    sort -z |
    xargs -r -0 -I% -n1 bash -c 'exec_script "$@" || exit 255' _ %
```

Comment: Annoyingly I read the man pages, but only looked at the flags to see if an option existed and after some googling, I was convinced that it quits after the first error. Thank you!

Comment: TBH when I saw your question it surprised me that `xargs` quit at all. I've learned something new today too, thank you.

Comment: @HoshSadiq instead of that shell loop, you can do everything much simpler with `.. | xargs -0 sh -c 'exec_script "$@" || exit 255' sh` (adjust for the other options you're passing to xargs and your script).

Comment: Also, do the files really need to be sorted first? If not, you can get rid of xargs and use `find ... \( -exec script {} \; -o -quit \)` instead.

Comment: @mosvy actually I much prefer the loop, originally I didn't use it because the script was meant to run on a posix shell, meaning `-d` wasn't available for `read`, later I refactored it so it runs through the host's bash and only executes the scripts in the chroot, but I guess I didn't think to go back to looping. In addition, using the loop doesn't require exporting the variables and/or functions. And yes, it's a simple way of creating script execution order as there's some dependencies and for some reason find does not sort them correctly though I've prefixed them with numbers.

Comment: @mosvy elegant alternative. Hope you don't mind, I've added it to the answer. If you want to write your own answer do rollback mine to match.

Comment: @HoshSadiq I'd assumed no POSIX requirement because you explicitly called `xargs ... bash`. And [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html) doesn't yet support NULL-terminated lines either.

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` is quite troublesome because it only stops when exiting with 255, then, using `set -eo pipefail` will be completely void when exporting a function, unless you use a subshell to encapsulate the `set -eo pipefail` failure and propagate it with `255`.

On this example, comment out the `errornow` line to see the difference:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -x
set -eo pipefail

parallel_uploads="4"
s3_bucket_name="backup"

all_files=(
"/12.pbd"
"/13.pbd"
"/14.pbd"
"/15.pbd"
"/16.pbd"
"/17.pbd"
"/18.pbd"
"/19.pbd"
"/20.pbd"
"/21.pbd"
"/22.pbd"
"/23.pbd"
"/24.pbd"
"/25.pbd"
"/26.pbd"
"/27.pbd"
)


# Workaround for the posix shell bug they call it feature
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65532/why-does-set-e-not-work-inside-subshells-with-parenthesis-followed-by-an-or
function acually_upload_to_s3()
{
    set -x;
    set -eu -o pipefail;

    printf 'Doing some\n';
    sleeptime="$(( RANDOM % 50 + 1 ))"
    sleep "$sleeptime";

    erroring_some;
    printf 'Doing more some\n';
}

function upload_to_s3()
{
    set -x;
    set -eu -o pipefail;
    # https://superuser.com/questions/403263/how-to-pass-bash-script-arguments-to-a-subshell
    /bin/bash -c "acually_upload_to_s3 $(printf "${1+ %q}" "$@")" || exit 255
}

function upload_all()
{
    export s3_bucket_name;
    export -f upload_to_s3;
    export -f acually_upload_to_s3;

    # https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566834/xargs-does-not-quit-on-error
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003418/calling-shell-functions-with-xargs
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441509/how-to-write-a-process-pool-bash-shell
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356100/how-to-wait-in-bash-for-several-subprocesses-to-finish-and-return-exit-code-0
    printf "'%s'\n" "${all_files[@]}" | xargs \
            --max-procs="$parallel_uploads" \
            --max-args=1 \
            --replace={} \
            /bin/bash -c 'time upload_to_s3 "$s3_bucket_name" "{}"';
}

time upload_all \
    && printf '%s Successfully uploaded all files\n' "$(date)" \
    || printf '%s Error: Could not upload some files\n'  "$(date)";
```

Example output:

```bsh
$ bash upload_to_s3_glacier_deep.sh
+ set -eo pipefail
+ parallel_uploads=4
+ s3_bucket_name=backup
+ all_files=("/12.pbd" "/13.pbd" "/14.pbd" "/15.pbd" "/16.pbd" "/17.pbd" "/18.pbd" "/19.pbd" "/20.pbd" "/21.pbd" "/22.pbd" "/23.pbd" "/24.pbd" "/25.pbd" "/26.pbd" "/27.pbd")
+ upload_all
+ export s3_bucket_name
+ export -f upload_to_s3
+ export -f acually_upload_to_s3
+ printf ''\''%s'\''\n' /12.pbd /13.pbd /14.pbd /15.pbd /16.pbd /17.pbd /18.pbd /19.pbd /20.pbd /21.pbd /22.pbd /23.pbd /24.pbd /25.pbd /26.pbd /27.pbd
+ xargs --max-procs=4 --max-args=1 '--replace={}' /bin/bash -c 'time upload_to_s3 "$s3_bucket_name" "{}"'
+ set -eu -o pipefail
++ printf ' %q' backup /12.pbd
+ /bin/bash -c 'acually_upload_to_s3  backup /12.pbd'
+ set -eu -o pipefail
++ printf ' %q' backup /13.pbd
+ /bin/bash -c 'acually_upload_to_s3  backup /13.pbd'
+ set -eu -o pipefail
++ printf ' %q' backup /14.pbd
+ /bin/bash -c 'acually_upload_to_s3  backup /14.pbd'
+ set -eu -o pipefail
+ printf 'Doing some\n'
Doing some
+ sleeptime=3
+ sleep 3
+ set -eu -o pipefail
++ printf ' %q' backup /15.pbd
+ /bin/bash -c 'acually_upload_to_s3  backup /15.pbd'
+ set -eu -o pipefail
+ printf 'Doing some\n'
Doing some
+ sleeptime=49
+ sleep 49
+ set -eu -o pipefail
+ printf 'Doing some\n'
Doing some
+ sleeptime=13
+ sleep 13
+ set -eu -o pipefail
+ printf 'Doing some\n'
Doing some
+ sleeptime=30
+ sleep 30
+ erroring_some
environment: line 5: erroring_some: command not found
+ exit 255

real    0m3.146s
user    0m0.045s
sys 0m0.123s
xargs: /bin/bash: exited with status 255; aborting
+ erroring_some
environment: line 5: erroring_some: command not found
+ exit 255

real    0m13.149s
user    0m0.015s
sys 0m0.123s
xargs: /bin/bash: exited with status 255; aborting

real    0m13.271s
user    0m0.075s
sys 0m0.337s
++ date
+ printf '%s Error: Could not upload some files\n' 'Fri, Nov 19, 2021 22:00:30'
Fri, Nov 19, 2021 22:00:30 Error: Could not upload some files
```